# Restoring Cassandra snapshot in YugabyteDB YCQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am trying to restore datastax cassandra database to YugabyteDB. Is it possible to restore a snapshot created on datastax cassandra to YugabyteDB?
Also, I can see something as `bin/yb-bulk-load.sh` but could not find its documentation.
Can we use this utility for data copy from cassandra to YugabyteDB?
Apart from the regular `COPY` command, Is there any other utility that I can use for data from copy from source to target yugabyte?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to restore snapshot created on datastax cassandra to
> yugabytedb.

No, it is not. The storage is different underneath.

> Also I am can see something as yb-bulk-load.sh in bin directory but
> could not find its documentation. Can we use this utility for data
> copy from cassandra to yugabyte.

I believe this is used to copy YugabyteDB sst file between different clusters, not importing from cassandra.

> Apart from regular COPY command , Is there any other utility that I
> can use for data from copy from source to target ( yugabyte )_

You can use `cassandra-loader` for big datasets: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/manage/data-migration/ycql/bulk-import/#large-datasets-gbs